# $X_{n}$ converges in probability where $X_{n}=\frac{Y_{n}}{n}$

Tags: self-study, convergence

Let $Y_{n}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables and $X_{n}=\frac{Y_{n}}{n}$ . show that $X_{n}$ converges in probability. decide whether $X_{n}$ converges a.e or not.

thanks for help.

Comment: What happens if $\mathbb E[Y_n] < \infty$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @conjectures. I think we can use borel-cantelli